# Y-axis getting cut off in D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, d3.js

The Y axis in my bar chart is getting cut off and I do not know why. Here is how it looks...
[d3 bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdpWX.png)...

and here is my code so far...

BarChart.js

```
import { csv, scaleBand, scaleLinear, max } from 'd3';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


const csvURL = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/0ac4077c7fc6390f5dd33bf5c06cb5ff/raw/605c54080c7a93a417a3cea93fd52e7550e76500/UN_Population_2019.csv';

const width = 960;
const height = 500;
const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 200 };

export default function BarChart() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const row = d => {
            d.Population = +d['2020']
            return d
        }
        csv(csvURL, row).then(data => {
            setData(data.slice(0, 10))
        });
    });

    if (!data) {
        return <pre>Loading...</pre>
    }

    const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;

    const yScale = scaleBand()
        .domain(data.map(d => d.Country))
        .range([0, innerHeight]);
    
    const xScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, max(data, d => d.Population)])
        .range([0, innerWidth])

    return (
        <svg width={width} height={height}>
            <g transform={`translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top}`}>
                {xScale.ticks().map(tickValue => (
                    <g transform={`translate(${xScale(tickValue)},0)`}>
                        <line y2={innerHeight} stroke="black" />
                        <text style={{textAnchor: 'middle'}} y={innerHeight + 5} dy=".71em">{tickValue}</text>
                    </g>
                ))}
                {yScale.domain().map(tickValue => (
                    <g transform={`translate(0,${yScale(tickValue)})`}>
                        <text style={{ textAnchor: 'end' }}>
                            {tickValue}
                        </text>
                    </g>
                ))}
                {data.map((d) => (
                <rect x={0} y={yScale(d.Country)} width={xScale(d.Population)} height={yScale.bandwidth()} />
                ))}
            </g>
        </svg>
    );
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import BarChart from './BarChart/BarChart';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='barChartContainer'>
        <BarChart />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.App {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #61dafb;
  text-align: center;
}

.App {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #61dafb;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.barChartContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

svg {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin: 5rem;
}
```

I have tried messing around with margin left per [this other suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54584606/last-y-axis-label-getting-cut-off), but for me it only increases space to the right of the bar chart, which is the most confusing.
When I increase margin.right, the right side margin increases. When I increase margin.left, again the right side margin increases.

Here are a few examples:

`const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 };`
[right: 20, left: 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09lpC.png)

`const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 200 };`
[right: 20, left: 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brv78.png)

`const margin = { top: 20, right: 200, bottom: 20, left: 20 };`
[right: 200, left: 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJX2A.png)

`const margin = { top: 20, right: 200, bottom: 20, left: 200 };`
[right: 200, left: 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeXSE.png)

hope this helps my explanation of the issue.

Comment: That's just a typo, you are missing a parenthesis here, before the last backtick: `<g transform={\`translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top}\`}>`.